# Can import some tablets from mysql 8.0.19 into a 5.7 database?

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process to transfer a wordpress site to a new server which uses an older version of mysql 5.7.23, so I want to start with a clean install of WordPress and database, so only the necessary tables will be brought to the new database, but the old server is using mysql 8.0.19.

So the question is: Can I import tables from mysql 8 to a database using an older mysql (5.7)? 
If so, do I need to do anything beside importing the dump?

Comment: one question should be more than enough to cover that topic.

Comment: The other question was about database, this one is about a table going to a different version database.

Comment: it doesn't matter make  a dump with only the tables and insert them into your databse. Or use wirkbench to itransfer. as you can see it is the same as the other question

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks

Comment: how many tables you want to transfer ?